# Create a True Count to select most likely possible column

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, angular, typescript

I am importing data from an excel file and am trying to locate certain information from their relevant columns by using RegEx to locate columns that have the data that I am looking for. However, the regex is imperfect because sometimes the expressions are found in more than one column. So to account for this basically I want to make some sort of internal counter that will count the number of times that a column has one of the Regular Expressions that I have defined in the set. An example for this is happening can be found below.

```js
columnsWithDescription()
  {
    var refDesRegex = [/resistor/i,/capacitor/i,/res/i,/cap/i]

    var refDesColumnNumber = new Set();
    for (var expression of refDesRegex)
    {
      for (const row of this.data)
      {
        for (var cell = 0; cell<row.length; cell++)
        {
          if (expression.test(row[cell]))
          {
            refDesColumnNumber.add(cell)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

`data` is the excel sheet that has been imported. It is an array of arrays where each array is a row of the excel sheet.

I have experimented with using the forEach method on the resulting Set but this results an overall true count and doesn't isolate the results from each column number. I want to run the test on each value of the set and see how many times the value in the column that matches the cell index returns true and then isolate that row so I can push it into an array later.

Comment: What more information would you say would be needed? I've explained what this.data is and shown how I iterate through the data to get values into the set

Comment: 1. Why aren't you using just one regex: `/(resistor|capacitor|res|cap)/i`? 2. Create an array `let counters = new Array(n).fill(0);` where n is the maximum number of columns in your spreadsheet and then your inner loop is `if (expression.test(row[cell])) counters[cell]++;`. You don't need the `refDesColumnNumber` set at all.

Comment: I'm identifying the data from data that is submitted to me I don't have much control over how that data is organized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to say is: If you are interested in finding out which column of the spreadsheet had the most matches with any of the regular expressions, then:

1. You do not have to test each regular expression separately. You can test against one regular expression that is a "logical or" of the individual regular expressions.
2. You just need to keep a count for each column number the number of times that column was matched with the regular expression (in a dictionary).

Finally, you will need to sort that dictionary's keys and values based on the values and then the key associated with the maximum value is the result you are looking for.

```
columnsWithDescription()
{
  let regex = /(resistor|capacitor|res|cap)/i;
  let counts = {}; // dictionary of counts
  for (let row of this.data)
  {
    for (var cell = 0; cell < row.length; cell++)
    {
      if (regex.test(row[cell]))
      {
        // we have a match in column # cell
        if (cell in counts)
          counts[cell]++; // not the first time we've had a match in this column
        else
          counts[cell] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  /* the keys of the counts dictionary are the column numbers
     and the values are the number of times a match was found in that column
  */
  // sort the counts dictionary:
  // create the items array
  let items = Object.keys(counts).map(function(key) {
    return [parseInt(key), counts[key]]; // the keys are actually strings
  });
  // sort items array in descending order based on the values:
  items.sort(function(first, second) {
    return second[1] - first[1];
  });
  return items[0][0]; // this is the column number that had the most matches
}
```

Comment: ahhhh ok, I had misunderstood your previous comment apologies for that

Comment: this is fantastic and I appreciate the use of comments really conducive to understanding